# Relative layout, overlay

Tags: android, layout, overlay

I have RelativeLayout with a number ImageViews, which are added dynamically. Each view overlap 80% of previous view. I want to add onClick listener for views, but I have a problem:
OnClick event works like I've clicked on the last (top) view, even if I clicked on any other.

Comment: Posting sample code can help for others in finding your issue.

Answer (score 0):

newly added view's are overlapping by a fixed proportion (80 % ) so you can relate cordinate of touched point and selected view easily . so instead of ClickListener on ImageView use a touchListener on RelativeLayout .

for more help share your code .

Comment: I've found that instead of using margin I was using padding. It looks the same, but in case of padding top element overlap all other elements.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that, although the image *inside* the ImageView is.. say 100x100px, that the ImageView itself is taking up the rest of the screen with the image resource centered.

Hard to say without code.